# Force a Git Conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

For my Job I make an Introduction Presentation about Git.
I want to show how to resolve merge conflicts. But to do so I need to get a merge conflict. For demonstration purposes I wrote a simple HTML Document in this Document is a Table were the Participants enter there Name. Will this be enough to generate a conflict?

Comment: Make 2 branches edit the same file in the same place in each branch, try and merge one into the other. simple

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+produce+merge+conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to generate conflict

```
# init your repo
git init

# print some text to any given file
echo 'aaa' > a.txt

# commit to the current branch
git add a.txt && git commit -m "Commit1"

# create a new branch
git checkout -b branch1

# add code to the end of the file
echo 'bbb' >> a.txt

# commit to the current branch (b)
git add a.txt && git commit -m "Commit2"

# get back to master branch
git checkout master

# add code to the end of the file
# here the file will still have its original code
echo 'ccc' >> a.txt

# commit to the current branch (master)
git add a.txt && git commit -m "Commit3"

# now when you will try to merge you will have conflict
git merge b
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question :)

Create a new branch with `git checkout -b new-branch`, edit a line, make a commit.

Switch to the original branch, edit the **same line** with a different edits, make another commit.

Now `git merge new-branch`, and you'll a get a merge conflict! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many kinds of conflicts you can produce. Normally people think of modifying some lines in different ways on separate branches... that's fine. That's one type of conflict. But there are others.

- Take a pice of code (some lines from a file) and delete them. Take another branch and modify them. Then merge.
- Take a file and remove it. Then go to another branch and edit it. Then merge.
- Take a file and rename it. Then go to another branch and rename it some other way. Then merge.